# How to get Flight name based on From and To Fields in Django models?

Tags: django, database, django-models

I have a Model called **ticket** in Django.

```
class ticket(models.Model):
    From  = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    To = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Flightname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

We will get the From and To data from the Frontend. How to return the flightnames that match from and to.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ticket.objects.filter(From=from_data,To=to_data).values_list('Flightname',flat=True)
```

this will give you the list of all the Flightname matched.